# How to save changes of a saved text file in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, text

I have a text editor that can open text files `.txt`and puts the text in a textbox. The user can also save the text to a `.txt` file.

How can the user save the changes of that text file that was saved recently?

Also, If the user opened a `txt` file how can the text editor change the text file to what the user changed?

Hope you understood that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don't know what you've done so far I will take this from the beginning...

For this you will need these components:

A SaveFileDialog

An OpenFileDialog

Three buttons (or menuitems), labeled: "Save", "Save As", "Open"

And I actually recommed using a RichTextBox instead of a regular TextBox.

.

To start, we put a variable in the code to know what file was saved before:

```
Dim LatestFile As String
```

Then, go to the properties of your Save- and OpenFileDialog and put this in the Filter field:

```
Text files (*.txt)|*.txt
```

Then you double-click the SaveFileDialog which should write the SaveFileDialog_FileOk event in your code. There you put:

```
LatestFile = SaveFileDialog1.FileName
RichTextBox1.SaveFile(SaveFileDialog1.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)
```

And then double-click the OpenFileDialog, and enter this code:

```
LatestFile = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
RichTextBox1.LoadFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)
```

And then for the buttons:

The "Open" button:

```
OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
```

The "Save" button:

```
If Not LatestFile = "" Then
    RichTextBox1.SaveFile(LatestFile, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)
Else
    SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
End If
```

And the "Save As" button:

```
SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
```

.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for replying. I got the controls you said at the top and I am using a RichTextBox too. Thanks again!

Comment: I don't see how your answer will help in detecting if there was a change in the source text file, and then to reload the changed file.

Comment: He did not ask for looking for source file changes. He wanted to be able to open a file and put it's text in the TextBox and also be able to save the text in the TextBox to the recently saved file. I bet that was what he meant with "how can the TEXT EDITOR change the text file to what THE USER HAS CHANGED?". In my words "How can you change the text in the text editor to what the user opened?". This was how I understood it, and apparently also what he wanted. And he said "how can the text editor change the text file...". Not the reverse. But JDS404, correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question: you want your text editor application to detect changes that happened to the source text file that it is currently viewing to the user and if it detects a change, it should update its text box to display the latest file for the user.. am I right?

If that is the case, one way to do that is to use a Timer. Every time the timer tick event is triggered, you should check the date of the last modification to the file. If it is greater than the date that you have checked while opening the file for the first time, then the file had gone through some changes. Reload the file contents into the text box.

Another way (without using Timers) is to only check for the modification date once the application window is activated. Since the user will have to change the focus of the program to, say Notepad to do changes to the text file, then once the user returns focus to the Text Editor Application, use the Window Activate or Click event to check the file modification date.

Comment: No.. both these options are bad. A timer consumes precious CPU cycles unnecessarily, and the Activate method you suggested is unreliable since the file can be edited from anywhere (network etc.). The better way is to use the [FileSystemWatcher Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Yes, I agree with @PradeepKumar said. Sorry!